# Firebase users authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Working on iOS App, at the moment app have some futures:

- sign-in/log-in with phone number or with Apple
- read data
  Now i want to add logged users as a document in firestore collection "users". Where i want to store favourite documents from over firestore collection. BTW in app users haven't sensitive information.

My first scenario was:

1. User signing in.
2. App sends request to backend which create/update document with uid and array of favourites.
3. When user want to get list of favourites or add new, app sends request with uid (*Auth.auth().currentUser*), for detect current user.

But in firebase docs we have this:
*The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server, if you have one.*
BTW a lot of guides in internet offer save uid as key to communicate with backend.

I have anover another thought - save phone number or email adress instead uid. But i guess that scenario is bad.

Can anyone explain me best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference is that the UID is used to differentiate one user from another. it is a unique identifier that you can use to associate a document or collection to that specific user, but this is not used to authenticate a user, that is done with the JWT known as the `ID token` which for most of Firebase is handled and decoded passively.

You can share a user's uid to other users so the app can know what user owns sets of data, what users are in a team, etc. it should not be used alone to validate a user, however depending on your service, this information is available through the `context.auth` property or `request.auth` resource in Security Rules.